Linkedin API giving out 404 even when conversion rules are present
After reading https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads-reporting/conversions-api?view=li-lms-2024-02&tabs=http#api-error-details and making sure that conversion rules are setup on my profile which I can view too, I am sending this request to linkedin.
curl --location 'https://api.linkedin.com/rest/conversionEvents
 \
--header 'LinkedIn-Version: 202405' \
--header 'X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer {some token}' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{
    "conversion": "urn:lla:llaPartnerConversion:<ConversionRuleId>",
    "conversionHappenedAt": 1716256339000,
    "user": {
        "userIds": [
            {
                "idType": "SHA256_EMAIL",
                "idValue": "<someEmailInSHA256>"
            }
        ]
    }
}

The response I get is:
{
    "status": 404,
    "code": "RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND",
    "message": "No virtual resource found"
}

I'm not sure why I'm getting 404 as the resource was created, and I can view it on the dashboard. Other than, that I think I've created the request correctly.

I just made the request again from another postman window and now I get the error
{
"message": "Invalid request information supplied, indices [0] (0-indexed)",
"status": 403
}
